# How to build and publish a web service from command line

Tags: web-services, soap, java-ee-7

I am new to Java/Java EE trying to create and publish a simple Hello world sort of web service from **command line** (I know using an IDE Netbeans/Eclipse would probably make the job easier but I just want to do this manually for the first few times to learn how to set the directory/package structure and environment correctly).

So on **Macbook** having set the **CLASSPATH** variable to **/Users/koira.su/Development/Java/JAX-WS/HelloWorld/src/hello**, I issue the following command to build (and publish) the web service:

```
koira.su$ javac WebServicePublisher.java
```

However, the above command results into the following errors:

```
koira.su$ javac WebServicePublisher.java
WebServicePublisher.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
import hello.WebServiceImpl;
        ^
symbol:   class WebServiceImpl
location: package hello
WebServicePublisher.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
           Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/webservice/helloworld", new WebServiceImpl());
                                                                       ^
symbol:   class WebServiceImpl
location: class WebServicePublisher
2 errors
```

My service endpoint interface (SEI), implementation and publisher classes which I have put under **/Users/koira.su/Development/Java//JAX-WS/HelloWorld/src/hello** look like as follows:

**WebServiceInterface.java**

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface WebServiceInterface {
    @WebMethod String getHelloWorldAsString(String name);
}
```

**WebServiceImpl.java**

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "hello")
public class WebServiceImpl implements WebServiceInterface {

        @Override
        public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name) {
                return "Hello World of JAX-WS " + name; }
}
```

**WebServicePublisher.java**

```
public class WebServicePublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/webservice/helloworld", new WebServiceImpl());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile using

```
javac -d . *.java
```

Then run

```
java hello.WebServicePublisher
```

Be sure the needed libraries/jars are in the classpath

Comment: I can now compile the code, however when I do 'java hello.WebServicePublisher' I get this Exception: Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: class: hello could not be found
 at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(RuntimeModeler.java:1601)
...

Comment: You are missing some jars, so it is unable to run, if you have knowledge of maven, try to mavenize your project

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice and simple explanation of how to set your directory structure and build the run Java applications from command prompt which helped me to fix the issue:

http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated.